# UITextViewへの入力時の文字属性の変更について

Tags: swift

UITextViewに下記のようなRichText文字列が表示されているとします。
ああ　　　いい　　　うう
↑黒色　　↑赤色　　　↑青色

たとえば、緑色指定ボタンを事前に押して、「うう」の前に、
緑色でテキストを入力したい場合は、
どうすれば入力時の文字色の指定ができるのでしょうか？

一部文字色の変更は、下記のような実装で実現できますが、
入力時の色指定方法が分かりません。

```
var range: NSRange = NSRange(location: 1, length: 1)
var attributedString =     NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString:self.testUiText.attributedText)
attributedString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.redColor(), range: range)
self.testUiText.attributedText = attributedString
```

↑self.testUiText.attributedTextに代入すると、キャレットが一番後ろに
なってしまいます。

```
func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool
```

や

```
func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView)
```

で処理できるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UITextView`のプロパティ`typingAttributes`が使えそうです。

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView! // 対象のText View

    // UIButtonではなくて、UIBarButtonItemを使いました。
    @IBAction func changeTextColor(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        if sender.title == "Red" {
            textView.typingAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor()]
        } else if sender.title == "Green" {
            textView.typingAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.greenColor()]
        } else {
            textView.typingAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blueColor()]
        }
    }
}
```

`tyoingAttributes`は、NSAttributedStringのAttributesとおなじ`Dictionary`です。
キーボード入力の文字の色が変化します。

Comment: ありがとうございます。参考になりました！